# How do you see a list of closed questions?

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions, search

I'm not sure if I have the privileges to see them. But, in theory, how would someone with the appropriate privileges see a list of questions that have been closed? Or perhaps a list of still-open questions sorted by numbers of votes to close?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try searching for: `closed:yes`

You can see more search tips [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Comment: Thanks! .......

Comment: At 10k you can also access pending votes, but I've just [proposed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239009/162102) that this be lowered to 3k, the reputation needed to cast close/reopen votes.

Answer (score 2):

At 10k, you can access "[Moderator Tools](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)" which includes a list of [recently closed questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Close&daterange=last30days)), and questions that include recent close votes.